# Continuity of distance function and its generalization

Tags: general-topology, analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

The starting is an easy undergraduate problem. The distance function $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is continuous. Please check if my proof is correct. If it is wrong please give some hint for the accurate proof.

From the triangular inequality we can say $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(y,z)$ i.e. $d(x,y) - d(z,y) \le d(x,z)$

Interchanging the role of $x$ and $y$ we shall get $|d(x,y) - d(z,y)| \le d(x,z)$.

Now for any $\epsilon > 0$ $|d(x,y) - d(z,y)| < \epsilon$ when $d(x,z) < \delta$ where $\epsilon = \delta$.

Thus $d$ is uniformly continuous and hence continuous.

The main problem is here.

1. I am thinking to prove it by using the open set definition of continuous function in a general topological space. Basis open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric is open intervals $(a,b)$. Its inverse in the metric space will be an open set. How to prove it?
2. Can we generalize the concept of distance function to an arbitrary order topology? I want to say if we can replace the range $\mathbb{R}$ of the distance function $d$ by a linear continuum or an arbitrary order topology.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you show that $|d(x,y)-d(z,y)|<ϵ$ when $d(x,z)<ϵ$, then this tells you that the function
$$X\to \Bbb R\\
x\mapsto d(x,y)$$
is uniformly continuous. However, you want to show that the function
$$d:X\times X\to\Bbb R\\
(x,y)\to d(x,y)$$
is continuous. To do that, show continuity at a point $(x_1,y_1)$. For an $ϵ>0$ find a $δ$ s.t. $|d(x_1,y_1)-d(x_2,y_2)|<ϵ$ whenever $D((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2))<δ$, where $D$ is the distance function on $X\times X$ which is defined as
$$D((x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_2))=d(x_1,x_2)+d(y_1,y_2)$$
**Hint:** Use the equation $|d(x_1,y_1)-d(y_1,x_2)|<d(x_1,x_2)$ and a similar one.

Comment: @StefanH Thank you for your reply. Whatever you have written is clear to me. What for other two questions?

Comment: On occasion, metrics are [generalized to arbitrary ordered fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_metric) other than $\Bbb R,$ and sometimes [to other directed sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Extended_metrics).

Comment: @Cameron Buie. Thank you for your links. It was unknown to me.

Answer (score 3):

In general,if $X,Y$ are any spaces, a function $f:X\times X\to Y$ may have the property that the functions  $f^{(1)}_a:X\to Y$ and $f^{(2)}_a:X\to Y$ are continuous for every $a\in X,$ where $f^{(1)}_a(x)=f(a,x)$ and $f^{(2)}_a(x)=f(x,a),$ and yet $f$ may still not be continuous.

What you need to show is that when $u,v\in \mathbb R$ with $u<v$ then $d^{-1}(u,v)=\{(a,b)\in X:u <d(a,b)<v\}$ is open in the space $X\times X.$

An open set in $X\times X$ is a union of a family of sets of the form  $C\times D$ where $C,D$ are open balls in $X.$ So it suffices to show that if $(a,b)\in d^{-1}(u,v)$ then $C\times D\subset d^{-1}(u,v)$ for some open balls $C,D$ of $X$ with $(a,b)\in C\times D.$ That is, with $a\in C$ and $b\in D.$

For $d(a,b)\in (u,v),$ let $w=\min (d(a,b)-u,\; v-d(a,b)).$ We have $w>0$ so $a\in B_d(a,w/2)$ and $b\in B_d(b,w/2)$.

For $a'\in B_d(a,w/2)$ and $b'\in B_d(b,w/2)$ we have $$\text {(i)} \quad d(a',b')\leq d(a',a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b')<w/2+d(a,b)+w/2\leq v$$  and  we have $$\text {(ii) }\quad  d(a,a')+d(a',b')+d(b',b)\geq d(a,b)$$  which implies $$\text {(ii') }\quad  d(a',b')\geq d(a,b)-d(a,a')-d(b',b)>d(a,b)-w/2-w/2\geq  u.$$ Therefore $$(a,b)\in d^{-1}(u,v)\implies (a,b)\in B_d(a,w/2)\times B_d(b,w/2)\subset d^{-1}(u,v).$$

Remark: For an example of an $f$ of my first paragraph, let $X=Y=\mathbb R,$ let $f(0,0)=0$ and let $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ when $x^2+y^2\ne 0.$ If $x\ne 0$ then $f(x,x)=1/2$ so $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x,x)=1/2\ne f(0,0)$. So $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{(a_n,b_n)\}_n\subseteq X\times X, (a,b)\in X\times X, (a_n,b_n)\to(a,b)$. We claim that $d(a_n,b_n)\to d(a,b)$.

First observe that $\forall n:d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a_n,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_n)$

$\implies \limsup d(a_n,b_n)\leq \limsup (d(a_n,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,b_n)) $

$=\limsup d(a_n,a)+\limsup d(a,b)+\limsup d(b,b_n)= d(a,b)$ (equality holds when distributing limit superior over two sequences when one of them is convergent and the other one is bounded $(*)$). Hence $\limsup d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a,b)$.

Conversely, $\forall n: d(a,b)\leq d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)+d(b_n,b)$

$ \implies d(a,b)\leq \liminf (d(a,a_n)+d(a_n,b_n)+d(b_n,b))=\liminf d(a_n,b_n)$

by an analogue of $(*)$. Thus $\limsup d(a_n,b_n)\leq d(a,b)\leq \liminf d(a_n,b_n)$, so that $d$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Take any open ball $B=(d(x,y)-\epsilon,d(x,y)+\epsilon)$ in $\Bbb{R}$. Then the inverse image $d^{-1}(B)\supseteq B_d(x,\epsilon/2)\times B_d(y,\epsilon/2)=U$, since for any $(z,t)\in U$, $d(z,t)\leq d(z,x)+d(x,t)<\epsilon/2+d(x,y)+d(y,t)<\epsilon+d(x,y)$. Similarly $d(x,y)<\epsilon+d(z,t)$.   So, $|d(x,y)-d(z,t)|<\epsilon$ as desired!